# Notation for vector with values $0$ and $1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors

For a real vector I know we write $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in\mathbb R^3$, which means $a_1\in\mathbb R$, $a_2\in\mathbb R$ and $a_3\in\mathbb R$.

Suppose instead I have a vector $b=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ where $b_1$, $b_2$ and $b_3$ only takes the values $0$ or $1$. What is the correct notation for this?

Comment: (b_1, b_2, b_3) ∈ {0,1}^3

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

$$(b_1,b_2,b_3)\in\{0,1\}^3$$

**Description**

For a smaller case of only one element, we write $b\in\{0,1\}$. For a two-element case, we can then write
$$(b_1,b_2)\in\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}\equiv\{0,1\}^2$$
And likewise we get for the three-element case
$$(b_1,b_2,b_3)\in\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}\equiv\{0,1\}^3$$

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)